# how can I add props inside class in html which already exists

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to add a class from another file as a prop, but I am not able to do it.

**file 1**

```
import React from 'react'
    
    const Button = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <button class={"btn btn-primary" props.classes }   type="submit" >{props.name}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Button
```

**file 2:**

```
<Button name="Sign Up" classes="me-sm-0"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pass the desired className in the props just like below:

```
 const Button = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className={`btn btn-primary ${props.className}`}   type="submit" >{props.name}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And this will be the Component used:

```
<Button name="Sign Up" className="me-sm-0"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have read your article carefully.
> I think your attempt to pass classes as props of the Button component worked really well.
> If there is one disappointment, the syntax of react jsx is wrong.
> In react jsx, the class property of html should be written as className.
> And use `...${regexp}`, one of the new features in es6.
> I attach the code below.

--App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Button from './Button';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button name="Sign Up" classes="me-sm-0" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

--Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
export default function Button(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className={`btn btn-primary ${props.classes}`} type="submit">
        {props.name}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```